# How to find the coordinates of a point given the length of the line & slope of the line segment

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

[image]

How do i find the coordinate of point D given that the length of AD is 5 and slope is $4/3$. I guess we should be able to write an equation which takes into account the length of AD which is 5 and the slope which is 4/3 to solve the coordinate point D.

Note: One my friends tried answering my above question using vector, something which i havent studied yet. So please give me solution in a more simple math.

Comment: As $A$ appears to be the origin, you have that $D$ is the point where the circle $x^2+y^2=5^2$ intersects with the line $y=-\frac 43x$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: slope should be $4/3$ and not negative because $-4/-3$ will equal to $4/3$

Comment: I answered according to your diagram. My apologies but that is kind of what you notice first

Comment: But there is a problem while solving the equation. As i will proceed solving the equation I will reach $x^2 = 9$ and now x can be -3 or 3. I think i should choose -3 as x value based on the context of other coordinates in the diagram ?

Comment: And I am getting x as -3 and y as -4 which is incorrect since correct answer is given as x as -4 and and y as -3

Comment: This shows that you miscalculated the slope and that it should be $\frac 34$

Comment: Ohh yeah. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that to go from B to C, you go to the left 4 units and up 3 units. Since this a parellelogram, to go from A to D you must do the same. (Edited to add: This is based on the drawing provided. Based on the text, you would say left 4 units and down 3 and would expect the drawing to be in the third quadrant, or lower left, where both values are negative).

Comment: The above was a smart way of solving it, I actually needed an equation to solve it. Which user raptor has given me. Thanks it solves my problem though.